# q - Application by name

Tags: kdb, q-lang

In the q for mortals [chapter on functions](http://code.kx.com/q4m3/6_Functions/) there is a little paragraph on "Application by name":

```
q)f:{x*x}
q)f[5]
_
q)`f[5]
25
q)`f 5
_
q).my.name.space.f:{2*x}
q)`.my.name.space.f[5]
```

I don't understand where and why this would be used.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we needed to call a function on a remote q server, and all we had was its name, then we could write

```
h (`.my.ns.function;x;y)
```

and receive a result - all with a symbol reference.